# how to insert multiple rows in first table and insert in other table using foreign key by single query

Tags: mysql

Due to the character limit, I couldn't choose a good title
My topic is a bit more complicated but I will explain it simplified here.

i have 3 table

the entity table

```
| id | name
|----|------
|  1 |   X
```

the entity_color table

```
| id | entID (foreign key entity.id) | color
|----|-------------------------------|-------
| 1  |               1               |  blue
|----|-------------------------------|-------
| 2  |               1               |  red
```

the stock_room table

```
| id | entColID (foreign key entity_color.id) | quntity
|----|----------------------------------------|----------
| 1  |                    1                   |    10
|----|----------------------------------------|----------
| 2  |                    2                   |    20
```

How can I insert this 5 rows ( 1 rows into entity + 2 rows into entity_color + 2 rows into stock_room ) into a mysql database with a commited query?

I don't think there is a way, but it's worth asking. That's why I want to benefit from your like-mindedness

______________ UPDATE _______________

Unfortunately, some users may irresponsibly and without understanding the question saysaid that this question is repetitiverepeated, so I musthave to point out thatthis point:

if we ignore the third table, this is a solution

```
START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO `entity` (`name`) VALUES (`x`);
    INSERT INTO `entity_color` (`entID`,`color`) VALUES (last_insert_id(),'blue'),(last_insert_id(),'red');
COMMIT;
```

but i have 3 table, it is not posibble that get two ids from entity_color with `last_insert_id()`

Comment: Why do you try to do this with one query? Whats wrong in using multiple queries?

Comment: There is no problem in calling `LAST_INSERT_IN()` multiple times for the different `INSERT INTO` queries and use the generated Ids in the other queries.

Comment: You can run the `INSERT INTO` queries for each individual row and get the created ID with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Then you use this value for the next `INSERT INTO` query. The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function is indeed not helpful for `INSERT INTO` queries which inserts multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT` statement can insert only to one table. You will need multiple `INSERT` statements.

You could use triggers to insert into other tables, but you can't pass the column values.

You can run multiple statements in the context of a transaction to make sure they all get committed.